# WebMethod not firing--JSON problem?

Tags: asp.net, json

I'm calling a WebMethod (ASP.NET) via AJAX (jQuery). If I create a version of the call with no params, it calls fine. When I pass my JSON into the real method, it doesn't get called (breakpoint not getting hit). Here's a sample of the JSON I'm passing in (array with 2 objects):

```
{
   "bills":[
      "{ 'Id': '1', 'Vote': 'true' },{ 'Id': '2', 'Vote': 'false' }"
   ]
}
```

Here's the WebMethod signature:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void LinkBillsToCandidate(List<JsonBillForCandidate> bills)
```

Here's the .NET object:

```
public class JsonBillForCandidate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool? Vote { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a problem with my JSON format? That's all I can think of that is preventing my call from going through.

Comment: Why are your array values in quotes?

Comment: I do think you have to make the `bills` parameter a `string` only and have to JSON-deserialize the string on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was as I had suspected. Some slight tweaking of the JSON did the trick. Here is the final JSON format that works:

```
{
   'bills':[
      {
         'Id':3,
         'Vote':true
      },
      {
         'Id':4,
         'Vote':false
      }
   ]
}
```

This ASP.NET method handles the JSON just fine:

```
[WebMethod]
public static void LinkBillsToCandidate(List<JsonBillForCandidate> bills)
{
    foreach (JsonBillForCandidate bill in bills)
    {
        BillLogic.LinkBillToCandidate(bill.Id, SessionHelper.CandidateId, bill.Vote);
    }

    NavigationHelper.GoToCandidate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because it's not finding the signature you're sending it (LinkBillsToCandidate(string))

As Uwe mentioned you can send it a string and deserialize it in server-side code using the JSON deserializing method:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx

Comment: In a recent project, I used the new [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) keyword of .NET 4 to save me from creating a real class to deserialize into. For smaller objects, this should be sufficient.